# Create a lineplot using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, matplotlib, errorbar

I have a dictionary that look as follows:

`my_dict={2:((4, 0.56),(8, 0.75)), 6:((3, 0.05),(5, 0.46)), 7: ((4, 0.99),(1, 0.56))}`

I want to create a line plot with error bars :
with dictionary keys on x axis and values on y axis. Further the items of the first tuple for every value need to be in one line and the items from the second tuple of every value need to be on the other.

something like the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_dict={2:((4, 0.56),(8, 0.75)), 6:((3, 0.05),(5, 0.46)), 7: ((4, 0.99),(1, 0.56))}

x_vals=[2,6,7]
line1=[4,3,4]
line2=[8,5,1]
errorbar1=[0.56,0.05,0.99]
errorbar2=[0.75,0.46,0.56]
plt.plot(x_vals, line1, linestyle='dotted')
plt.plot(x_vals, line2, linestyle='dotted')
plt.errorbar(x_vals, line1, yerr=errorbar1, fmt=' ')
plt.errorbar(x_vals, line2, yerr=errorbar2, fmt=' ')
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('yaxis')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Are you just trying to plot the data from your other question [Average values of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68704991/7758804)?

Comment: yeah... this does the job excellently though

Comment: I have added an update, which makes most of the other question unnecessary. We can easily just plot `rl` without the need for all the other code. You can see that all the plots are the same. Also, if the answer is useful, please also consider upvoting it. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to unpack the `keys` and `values` of `my_dict`.
- From `python >=3.6` `dicts` are [insertion ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/7758804), so the extracted values don't require sorting.
- **Tested in `python 3.8`, `pandas 1.3.1`, `matplotlib 3.4.2`, and `seaborn 0.11.1`**

```py
my_dict = {21: ((0.667, 0.126), (0.63, 0.068)), 52: ((0.679, 0.059), (0.637, 0.078)), 73: ((0.612, 0.211), (0.519, 0.143)), 94: ((0.709, 0.09), (0.711, 0.097))}

x_vals = my_dict.keys()

line1 = [v[0][0] for v in my_dict.values()]
line2 = [v[1][0] for v in my_dict.values()]

errorbar1 = [v[0][1] for v in my_dict.values()]
errorbar2 = [v[1][1] for v in my_dict.values()]

plt.plot(x_vals, line1, linestyle='dotted')
plt.plot(x_vals, line2, linestyle='dotted')
plt.errorbar(x_vals, line1, yerr=errorbar1, fmt=' ')
plt.errorbar(x_vals, line2, yerr=errorbar2, fmt=' ')
plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('yaxis')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Using `pandas`

- Tested with `pandas 1.3.1` and `matplotlib 3.4.2`
- This reduces the code from 13 to 7 lines.

```py
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {21: ((0.667, 0.126), (0.63, 0.068)), 52: ((0.679, 0.059), (0.637, 0.078)), 73: ((0.612, 0.211), (0.519, 0.143)), 94: ((0.709, 0.09), (0.711, 0.097))}

# load the dictionary into pandas
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index', columns=['line1', 'line2'])

# display(df)
             line1           line2
21  (0.667, 0.126)   (0.63, 0.068)
52  (0.679, 0.059)  (0.637, 0.078)
73  (0.612, 0.211)  (0.519, 0.143)
94   (0.709, 0.09)  (0.711, 0.097)

# separate the tuples to columns
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns, 1):
    df[[col, f'errorbar{i}']] = pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist(), index= df.index)

# display(df)
    line1  line2  errorbar1  errorbar2
21  0.667  0.630      0.126      0.068
52  0.679  0.637      0.059      0.078
73  0.612  0.519      0.211      0.143
94  0.709  0.711      0.090      0.097

# plot
ax = df.plot(y=['line1', 'line2'], linestyle='dotted', ylabel='y-axis', xlabel='x-axis', title='title', figsize=(8, 6))
ax.errorbar(df.index, 'line1', yerr='errorbar1', data=df, fmt=' ')
ax.errorbar(df.index, 'line2', yerr='errorbar2', data=df, fmt=' ')
```

[image]

### Update

- I realized that all of the previous code is to accommodate your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68704991/7758804).
- Everything from both questions can really be ignored, plotting is all about shaping the data to fit the plot API.
- If `rl` from the other question is used, it can be directly converted to a long form, and plotted with [`seaborn.pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html).

  - As you can see in the previous plots, the error bars overlap, making the plot more difficult to read. Here `dodge` is used to slightly offset the points, so the error bars don't overlap.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# using rl from the other question convert to a long form
rl = [{21: (0.5714285714285714, 0.6888888888888889), 52: (0.6153846153846154, 0.7111111111111111), 73: (0.7123287671232876, 0.6222222222222222), 94: (0.7127659574468085, 0.6)}, {21: (0.6190476190476191, 0.6444444444444445), 52: (0.6923076923076923, 0.6444444444444445), 73: (0.3698630136986301, 0.35555555555555557), 94: (0.7978723404255319, 0.7777777777777778)}, {21: (0.8095238095238095, 0.5555555555555556), 52: (0.7307692307692307, 0.5555555555555556), 73: (0.7534246575342466, 0.5777777777777777), 94: (0.6170212765957447, 0.7555555555555555)}]
df = pd.DataFrame(rl).melt(var_name='Sample Size')

df[['Train', 'Test']] = pd.DataFrame(df['value'].tolist(), index= df.index)
df.drop('value', axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df.melt(id_vars='Sample Size', var_name='Score')

# display(df)
   Sample Size  Score     value
0           21  Train  0.571429
1           21  Train  0.619048
2           21  Train  0.809524
3           52  Train  0.615385
4           52  Train  0.692308

# plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
p = sns.pointplot(data=df, x='Sample Size', y='value', hue='Score', ci='sd', dodge=0.25, linestyles='dotted')
p.set(ylabel='Mean of Trials', title='Score Metrics')
```

[image]

```py
# given df, you can still see the metrics with
dfg = df.groupby(['Sample Size', 'Score']).agg(['mean', 'std'])

# display(dfg)
                      value          
                       mean       std
Sample Size Score                    
21          Test   0.629630  0.067890
            Train  0.666667  0.125988
52          Test   0.637037  0.078042
            Train  0.679487  0.058751
73          Test   0.518519  0.142869
            Train  0.611872  0.210591
94          Test   0.711111  0.096864
            Train  0.709220  0.090478
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use list comprehension for this by replacing the hard-coded lists

```
x_vals=[2,6,7]
line1=[4,3,4]
line2=[8,5,1]
errorbar1=[0.56,0.05,0.99]
errorbar2=[0.46,0.75,0.56]
```

with

```
x_vals=sorted(my_dict.keys())
line1=[my_dict[k][0][0] for k in x_vals] # [4,3,4]
line2=[my_dict[k][1][0] for k in x_vals] # [8,5,1]
errorbar1=[my_dict[k][0][1] for k in x_vals] # [0.56,0.05,0.99]
errorbar2=[my_dict[k][1][1] for k in x_vals] # [0.46,0.75,0.56]
```